# Error while setting up an indexer on tsv data

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have a data in tsv format & I want to index it using azure search. So I have set up my indexer accordingly, and provided /t as delimiter.

I get following error:
Import configuration failed, error creating Indexer: "Error with data source: Row '1' in document 'mapping/v1/subscriptions.tsv' is malformed. Reason: Line 1 cannot be parsed using the current Delimiters.  Please adjust your data source definition in order to proceed."

I wanted to check following
1) are tsv files supported by indexer? (I think yes)
2) How should one provide delimiter if so?

Comment: Can you share your indexer configuration? There's a known issue with tab delimiters and that will help us determine if you're affected by the issue.

Comment: Also, could you share the name of your search service and the name of the indexer that you are having an issue with. If we determine that you might've been affected we can try to fix it from our end

Comment: {
 "name": "tsvindexer",
 "description": "Testing tsv indexing",
 "dataSourceName": "tsvtest",
 "targetIndexName": "tsvindex",
 "schedule": {
  "interval":"PT1H",
  "startTime": "2019-02-21T22:00:00Z"
 },
 "parameters": {
  "maxFailedItems": "0",
  "batchSize": "10",
  "configuration": {
   "parsingMode": "delimitedText",
   "indexedFileNameExtensions": ".tsv",
   "delimitedTextHeaders": "RowKey,TenantId,SubscriptionId,CountryCode,ProductName",
   "delimitedTextDelimiter": "\t",
   "dataToExtract": "contentAndMetadata"
  }
 }
}

Comment: above is the indexer configuration. Search service name:subscriptionmappingint

Comment: I couldn't find the indexer 'tsvindexer' in the service that you mentioned. Have you perhaps deleted it?

Comment: No I didn't delete. the thing is since i get this error while creation of indexer, it doesn't even create it . 

Also, I get the same error via rest api as well while creating indexer

Comment: Let me know if my above information helped. as i said indexer is not being created so you won't be able to see the details.